# Writing print statements to csv from loops without newlines

Tags: python, csv, newline

I have some code and am wondering how I can properly format it and save to a csv file. I haven't been able to find a question that answers this question in the way I want, and since I am fairly new to python I'm having trouble changing code that answers similar questions to something that suits my need.

It breaks down to the following:

```
assets = [asset_1, asset_2, asset_3]
for i in range(len(assets)):
    price = data.current(assets[i], "price")
```

Now if I

```
print price
```

it prints as

```
price 1
price 2
price 3
```

I can get it to print as `price 1, price 2, price 3` without trouble, but it seems pretty janky for me to write something like `print price[0], price[1], price[2], newline` especially when I hope to extend this to many more assets in the future. All the solutions I've come accross that remove the newlines then cause `price1, price2, price3, price1, price2...` and I want the newline to happen specifically after price 3. I have also been able to get it to export the data to a csv without trouble, but the csv just has one column similar to the first print statement. How can I get each of the 3 prices into a csv and then a newline?

I attempted to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45623167/writing-to-csv-with-for-loops) answer, and changed my print statements to follow suit, but got a syntax error when trying to print prices[index] index in my case being 0:2 (tried 1:3 in case but didn't work as expected)

Here is my actual code.

```
from catalyst.api import record, symbol, symbols
from datetime import datetime
import os, csv, pytz, sys
import catalyst


def initialize(context):

    # Portfolio assets list
    context.assets = [symbol("XMR_DASH"), symbol("BTC_XMR"), symbol("BTC_DASH")] 

    '''
    # Creates a .CSV file with the same name as this script to store results
    context.csvfile   = open(os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(__file__))[0]+'.csv', 'w+')
    context.csvwriter = csv.writer(context.csvfile)
    '''


def handle_data(context, data):

    date = context.blotter.current_dt # Current time for each iteration in the simulation
    price = data.current(context.assets, "price") 
    print price

    '''
    for i in range(0,3):
        price = data.current(context.assets[i], "price") 
        print price[any index gives syntax error]
    '''

def analyze(context=None, results=None):
    pass
    '''
    # Close open file properly at the end
    context.csvfile.close()
    '''


start = datetime(2017, 7, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0, pytz.utc)
end = datetime(2017, 7, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0, pytz.utc) 
results = catalyst.run_algorithm(start=start, end=end, initialize=initialize, 
                                 capital_base=10000, handle_data=handle_data, 
                                 bundle='poloniex', analyze=analyze, data_frequency='minute')
```

I don't need help with writing data to a csv, but do need help formatting the data that is written. Preferably an answer would also work with print statements so I can visualize what's going on before going to the csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simple print the array this way:

```
assets = [asset_1, asset_2, asset_3]
print(","join([str(data.current(assets[i], "price")) for i in assets]))
```

- `",".join(array)` joins the array with a comma between values. A Print will print the concatenated array, with a newline at the end
- `[str(data.current(assets[i], "price")) for i in assets]` builds the array of prices you want to concatenate

Comment: `data.current(assets[i], "price")` needs conversion to `str`??

Comment: maybe, maybe not. depends what the 'price' data is in the csv. csv usually comes as text output that needs to be cast as int or float to turn into a number. But yes,ok, it's safe to cast as string just in case.

Comment: Great, this is working for me. Thanks so much for the help and quick response. How can I mark this as closed like I see happen with other questions?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the below..

```
for i in range(0,3):
    price = data.current(context.assets[i], "price") 
    print price[any index gives syntax error]
```

To

```
price=[]
for i in range(0,3):
    price.append(data.current(context.assets[i], "price"))
print(','.join([str(x) for x in price])
```

And the issue you were facing I believe is that price is a single float/double/int and not a list of prices. Thus any index on price would fail. Now with this we created a price list.